# Vba code to apply autofill method if there is only 1 row

Tags: vba, excel

The Autofill method of the following code snippet works fine if there are more than 1 row but fails and gives runtime error 1004 in case of only 1 row, Kindly suggest the required changes.

```
Lastrow = ws3.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
ws1.Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=TEXT(RC[6],""000000000000"")&""-""&TEXT(RC[7],""0000"")"
ws1.Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=ws1.Range("A2:A" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: simpler to apply the formula to the range A2:A & LastRow in one go without autofill

Comment: ws1.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).FormulaR1C1 = 
    "=TEXT(RC[6],""000000000000"")&""-""&TEXT(RC[7],""0000"")"

Comment: Thanks,It works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really quick fix:

```
lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A2").FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[6],""000000000000"")&""-""&TEXT(RC[7],""0000"")"
If lastrow > 2 Then
    Range("A2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A2:A" & lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
End If
```

In general, it will work. And it gives an error to you, because it the lastrow is `1` and it cannot do the `AutoFill` with it.